# How to keep window open upon execution of Test Suite?

Tags: testing, automation, katalon-studio

How open our browser session at beginning of test suite, use same browser throughout test suite, then close at the end of the test suite, instead of closing browser at the end of each test case ? I know that you will need to use a redirect to the correct browser location like e.g. the test fails?

I try use set up test listeners that run before or after test suite / test case.

Comment: Why do you need this?

Answer (score 0):

Go to Project Settings > Execution and uncheck both "Terminate drivers after each Test Case" and Terminate drivers after each Test Suite".
[image]

Comment: I have it turned on, and unfortunately browsers open and don't always close either, I thought at the beginning of the first Test Case to make open browser and in the next Test Case to do only Navigate to Url but I don't know if it will work if, for example, one of the Test Cases in Test Suite fails.
I've heard of SetUp or teardown method... or Test Listeners